# How to make this query for this scenario in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table called `TransactionItem, ItemRelation`, below are my queries

```
     select sum(dqty) as QUANTITY FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionItem] 
    where ItemLookupCode='306519P0001' group by Tyear, Tmonth

 select 
    ItemLookupCode, convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4)) as SIZE from 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation] where ItemLookupCode='319348P0001' or 
    ChildItemLookupCode1='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode2='319348P0001' or 
    ChildItemLookupCode='319348P0001'
```

calculations

Result of my query of two tables 
[image: Result of my query of two tables]
As you can see the result on image, now I just want to divide all the values of quantity from first result by size from second result. For example

```
QUANTITY
6/48
64/48
167/48
31/48
2367/48
1664/48
8/48
```

How to do it in a single query?.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make it easier for people to help you could you put your query text into the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: `select sum(dqty) as QUANTITY FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionItem]
  where ItemLookupCode='306519P0001'
  group by Tyear, Tmonth
  
  select ItemLookupCode, convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4)) as SIZE  from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation]
  where ItemLookupCode='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode1='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode2='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode='319348P0001'
`  From these two query I want to do above calculations

Comment: Second table you get only one row always

Comment: Is the ItemLookupCode supposed to be the same in each table? Right now it's different. 306519... vs 319348...

Comment: @Mansoor yes, My target is I want to divide the `QUANTITY` value from first query by `SIZE` from second query

Comment: @jeffcarey For your doubt I have to explain more. Itemlookupcode what i am looking,it may match with my second query field of `ItemLookupCode or ChilItemLookupCode1 or ChilItemLookupCode2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT QUANTITY / SIZE QUANTITY FROM (
    select sum(dqty) as QUANTITY
    FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionItem]
    where ItemLookupCode='306519P0001'
    group by Tyear, Tmonth
) A
CROSS JOIN (
    select ItemLookupCode, convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4)) as SIZE
    from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation]
    where
        ItemLookupCode='319348P0001'
        or ChildItemLookupCode1='319348P0001'
        or ChildItemLookupCode2='319348P0001'
        or ChildItemLookupCode='319348P0001'
) B
```

Comment: Note: this will only work properly if you have a single result for the second query...

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell about cross join, how it works?

Comment: Cross joins do not require any conditions (ON clause), each row on the left is duplicated times the number of rows on the right and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate size and put it in a variable. Then you can use the same variable for division in the second query.

```
declare @size int;

set @size= (Select top 1 convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4)) as SIZE from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation] 
where ItemLookupCode='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode1='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode2='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode='319348P0001')

select sum(dqty)/@size as QUANTITY FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionItem] 
where ItemLookupCode='306519P0001' 
group by Tyear, Tmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #Tbl1(Qty INT)
CREATE TABLE #Tbl2(Size INT)

INSERT INTO #Tbl1(Qty)
SELECT 6  UNION ALL
SELECT 64 UNION ALL
SELECT 167

INSERT INTO #Tbl2(Size)
SELECT 48

SELECT Qty / (SELECT Size FROM #Tbl2)
FROM #Tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable to store the sum. then we can use this variable while dividing in the next query.

```
Declare @QUANTITY float;

select @QUANTITY=sum(dqty) 
FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionItem] 
where ItemLookupCode='306519P0001'
group by Tyear, Tmonth 


select ItemLookupCode
,convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4)) as SIZE, convert(INT,SUBSTRING(ItemLookupCode,8,4))/@QUANTITY
from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation] 
where (ItemLookupCode='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode1='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode2='319348P0001' or ChildItemLookupCode='319348P0001')
```